# How to add Chartboost dependency to my LibGDX project?

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, chartboost

I want to add Chartboost to my LibGDX game, but I don't know how to add it as a dependency to Gradle. Also, Chartboost uses Google Play Game Services, so I need to add both of them to Gradle. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems the chartboost jar is not published to a public maven repository so you need to reference it by file:

```
dependency {
    // references a file relative to the project folder
    files('libs/chartboost.jar')
}
```

to add google play services you can use reference it like this:

```
dependencies {
    // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'

    // Note: these libraries require the "Google Repository" and "Android Repository"
    //       to be installed via the SDK manager.
}
```

Comment: On which dependency do i need to put this?